# Computer restarts instead of shutting down

Tags: 11.04, power-management, shutdown, pm-utils

My Ubuntu 11.04 will not shutdown when I tell it to; it will instead restart the computer.

Comment: Are you using the power button (hardware) to shutdown or the menu entry? What happens if you enter "sudo shutdown -P now" in the terminal?

Comment: did you install `laptop-mode-tools` ? I had the same problem when I installed this package.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try

```
sudo shutdown -P now
```

If that works, then the problem is related to the desktop environment that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

As this problem can come from bad interactions between hardware, if you're technically skilled, you might want to try to rule out that possibility by booting your PC with as many components as possible disconnected.

My mother had this exact same problem and, when I upgraded her to a new PC a few months ago, the problem followed along. I ended up tracking it down to her PCI FaxModem card. When I removed that, the system started shutting down properly.

(And I'm pretty sure, back when we first built the machine, we assumed it was a BIOS bug because even Windows suffered from it)

Answer (score 0):

I used to have that issue with an old PC. If I recall correctly, it would reboot if I told it to shut down, but if I told it to reboot, then it would halt, but not power off. It was a weird hardware issue and I can't remember if I attempted to fix it or if I just learned to live with it.

You should file a bug on http://www.launchpad.net, probably using linux--generic as the package. Provide as much details as you possibly can, and maybe it'll get fixed.